# python script stops at import statement when script is run as cronjob

Tags: python, bash, cron

I'm executing a python script every 30 minutes with cron, but it stops at the import statement and I don't understand why because I don't get any feedback.

In my crontab I have `*/30 * * * * sh exec_script.sh`

The file `exec_script.sh` is

```
cd /home/ziofil/python_scripts
python script_30_mins.py
```

In the python script I have

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(filename="explicit_log.txt",level=logging.DEBUG)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

logger.debug("script is executed")

# in the python_scripts folder there is a subfolder utilities/ that
# contains utility_1.py, were I define the class Utility
from utilities.utility_1 import Utility
logger.debug("Utility loaded")

utility = Utility()
logger.debug("object creation")

utility.do_your_thing()
logger.debug("done its thing")
```

If I execute `python script_30_minutes.py` from the terminal, everything works just fine, but with cron the execution stops at the `import` statement (I read "script is executed", but noting else).

What is going wrong?

UPDATE: I put the import statement in a `try/except` block and it logged the exception: "No module named utilities.utility_1". I also tried to set the PYTHONPATH variable in the shell script to `/home/ziofil/python_scripts`, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: In most cases it is because cron doesn't have the PATH variable set. So it cannot find "python" in your file system. Try following in your _exec_scripts.sh_: `/usr/lib/python2.7 script_30_mins.py` (check if the path exists, perhaps you have another python version so the path differs).

Comment: But the python script _is_ executed: it creates the file "explicit_log.txt" and it writes a line in it. Do you think it's still a PATH variable issue?

Comment: @UweMannl: It's not a problem with `PATH`. Output is produced, so the Python interpretter is executing.

Comment: @mhawke You're right, saw it now. So it seems the interpreter stops at `from utilities.utility_1 import Utility`. The solution should be your answer in this case.

Comment: @UweMannl you were right: it was an issue of which python binary cron uses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out what the problem was. @UweMannl was right all along. After @mhawke pointed out that cron's environment is different than the one of my terminal, I thought that perhaps also the python binary could be different and indeed it was: I want `/home/ziofil/anaconda3/bin/python` and cron was using `/usr/bin/python`.

I modified the last line of the script to `/home/ziofil/anaconda3/bin/python script_30_mins.py` and everything works!

Answer (score 2):

`cron` runs processes with a different environment to that of your terminal. Possibly you have set `PYTHONPATH` in your terminal, but not in your cron environment. If that is the case you can add it to your shell script:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/home/ziofil/python_scripts/whatever:$PYTHONPATH
cd /home/ziofil/python_scripts
python script_30_mins.py
```

Comment: I just checked and PYTHONPATH is not set in my terminal either, `echo $PYTHONPATH` returns a blank line. Nevertheless, I set it to `.../python_scripts` in the shell script but no luck. I also wrapped the import statement in a try/except and I logged the exception: “No module named utilities.utility_1”.

Comment: @Ziofil Do you run the cron as normal user oder root? (Is this your crontab or do you edit it with sudo?) ... PS: your export should be `export PYTHONPATH=/home/ziofil/python_scripts/:$PYTHONPATH`

Comment: Ah! I found the problem. I added "echo `which python` > whichpy.txt" in the script and I found out that cron is using /usr/bin/python which is v2.7.12, whereas my terminal uses `/home/ziofil/anaconda3/bin/python`, which is v3.6.3. I changed the call to the script to `/home/ziofil/anaconda3/bin/python script_30_mins.py` and everything works fine.