# "ImportError: No module named praw" error when running python script in crontab

Tags: python, cron, praw

I have a python script that uses `praw`. When I run the script it works perfectly, but when I try to run in through `crontab` I continue to get:

```
import praw ImportError: No module named praw
```

I've tried everything I can think of and can't find any posts with the same issues. Not sure why it's doing this. Would appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: Try adding this line before the import statement:
!pip install praw

Comment: This question might help: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48597496/21945. Basically cron's environment is different to that of your terminal so you need to figure out what the pertinent differences are.

Answer (score 0):

First [create a python virtual environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45293436/how-to-specify-python-version-used-to-create-virtual-environment) with the specific python version you use. Then activate it and install your required packages using pip.

Then in your `crontab` you can first activate the virtual env and then run the python script you have. Either you can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7031758/4928615) or follow.

```
0 0 * * * /path/to/your/virtualenv/bin/python /absolute/path/for/your/python script>
```

Hope this helps!